# Compute $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\log(x^2+y+1)}{x^2+y^2+x^3 y}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

According to Wolfram Alpha, the following limit does not exist:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\log(x^2+y+1))}{x^2+y^2+x^3 y}$$

My approach:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\log(x^2+y+1)}{x^2+y^2+x^3 y}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^2+y+1}{e^(x^2+y^2+x^3 y)}=\frac{1}{e^0}=1$$

But I don't know if that's ok.

Comment: You can't arbitrarily take things to be powers of e, and not really sure what is going on in the denominator.

Comment: Two problems with your approach: (1) is that $e^{a/b} \neq e^a/e^b$ and (2) $\lim f(x,y) \neq \lim e^{f(x,y)}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't think this limit exists, you should try to let $(x,y)$ approach $(0,0)$ along different paths. Common paths to consider are approaching $(0,0)$ along the $x$-axis, $y$-axis, or a line $y = mx$. If you find two paths along which you get two different values of the limit, then you can conclude the limit DNE.

For example, here as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ along the $x$-axis (so $(x,0) \to (0,0)$) we have the limit (after simplifying)

$$
    \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\log(x^2 + 1)}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x}{2x(x^2+1)} = 1,
$$

where the first equality follows from L'Hopital's rule. Can you find another path along which the limit does not equal $1$?

Comment: The problem is that i initially thought that the limit exist, thats why the absurd "power of e" approach.